# Can you have a single domain for multiple OpenShift apps?

Tags: dns, openshift, cname

I'd like to run PHP/WordPress on one and Node.js/mailin (for email forwarding) on another. Both should use the same domain and no sub-domains. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible with OpenShift, you would need to put each application under it's own sub-domain.

Comment: Can an app running on mail.domain.com receive mail directed at address@domain.com? May sound like a dumb question, but I don't know s*** about email.

Comment: No, mail runs over port 25 for SMTP, and requires another mail server to communicate with, not a web application.

Comment: Node.js has mail servers that can run on port 25. Does OpenShift not allow access to that port?

Comment: You will not be able to bind to port 25 on OpenShift. The only externally addressable ports of your app would be 80, 443, 8000 and 8443, for which you internally bind your app to 8080 (details [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html)). Maybe something like [mailgun](https://blog.openshift.com/email-in-the-cloud-with-mailgun/) or [SendGrid](https://developers.openshift.com/en/marketplace-sendgrid.html) will suit your needs.